# How to implement BLENC encoding in PHP in xampp server

Tags: php, encoding, xampp, blenc

I have googled a couple of day about this topic and dint find any good tutorial or link about this topic. I need to implement BLENC encryption in my php desktop application code, but not familiar with it.

Please anyone provide me a step by step procedure for doing it. form enabling BLENC in php server to encryption and execution of code in php.

I alredy tried with copy php_blenc.dll file in php/ext folder and enbled it in php.ini file , but it result a waring while apache start.